# Sort Values of Multiple Columns Per-Row and Update Columns Accordingly?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, quicksort

I'm trying to replace a function in VBA that goes row-by-row and grabs the values of 3 columns in a table, sorts them in ascending order, and places them in the correct column. Here's an example of what the table looks like before and after:

Before:

| ID | Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 96 | 25 | 13 | 84 |
| 97 | 101 | 78 | 8 |

Pseudo Code

```
    For each rw in tblSQL:
        array = quicksort(rw.col1, rw.col2, rw.col3)
        update tblSQL SET rw.col1 = array(0), 
                          rw.col2 = array(1),
                          rw.col3 = array(2)
```

After:

| ID | Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 96 | 13 | 25 | 84 |
| 97 | 8 | 78 | 101 |

This was never supposed to be a permanent solution but it ran lightning fast when the data was local. However, we now use an Azure SQL DB, and it's too slow for my liking to go updating row-by-row with an ODBC connection.

Is there a way to do this with TSQL or something else in SQL Server? I'm having a hard time finding any answers because all my search results are about sorting *all* the records in a column, not the individual values in each row across the columns.
I could also create a quick and easy Azure function using Python or C# but I'm not sure if that would give me any performance gains because I'd still need to go row-by-row with some type of remote connection correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `UNPIVOT` and then `PIVOT` with a new order.

```
declare @MyTable table (ID int, ColumnA int, ColumnB int, ColumnC int);

insert into @MyTable (ID,   ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnC)
values
(96, 25, 13, 84),
(97, 101, 78, 8);

with cte1 as (
    select Id, ColumnName, ColumnValue
    from @MyTable
    unpivot (
        ColumnValue for ColumnName in (ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnC)
    ) up
), cte2 as (
    select id, ColumnValue
      , 'Column' + char(64 + row_number() over (partition by Id order by ColumnValue)) ColumnName
    from cte1
), cte3 as (
    select id, ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnC
    from cte2
    pivot (
        sum(ColumnValue) for ColumnName in ([ColumnA],[ColumnB],[ColumnC])
    ) p
)
update my set
    ColumnA = c3.ColumnA
    , ColumnB = c3.ColumnB
    , ColumnC = c3.ColumnC
from cte3 c3
inner join @MyTable my on my.Id = c3.id;

select * from @MyTable;
```

Returns

| id | ColumnA | ColumnB | ColumnC |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 96 | 13 | 25 | 84 |
| 97 | 8 | 78 | 101 |

Comment: @GAlvidrez this isn't any less hardcoded than the case approach... you still have to know your column names in advance.

Comment: Yes but unlike CASE this solution will work if any fields get added or removed without adding a exponential amount of logic to the procedure. Let's say another 2 fields get added, that would more than double the number of CASE statements.

Comment: Yep, this is going to be the better answer if it's any more complicated than stated, I'd be interested in how it performs at scale (not nessecarily relevant depending on usage, but interesting)

Comment: Yeah I can't imagine it performs well, but nothing is going to be great for this sort of thing.

Comment: @PatrickHurst Well as of now it's intended to stay simple but you know how these things go. So far about 4000 records run in 206ms

Comment: @PatrickHurst 16000 rows in 4200ms

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a job for CASE!

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #EverydayImShuffling
CREATE TABLE #EverydayImShuffling (ID INT, ColA INT, ColB INT, ColC INT)
INSERT INTO #EverydayImShuffling (ID, ColA, ColB, ColC) VALUES
(96, 25 ,   13, 84),
(97, 101,   78, 8 )

UPDATE #EverydayImShuffling
   SET ColA = CASE WHEN ColA < ColB AND ColA < ColC THEN ColA
                   WHEN ColB < ColC THEN ColB
                   ELSE ColC
               END,
       ColB = CASE WHEN ColA > ColB AND ColA < ColC THEN ColA
                   WHEN ColB < ColA AND ColB > ColC THEN ColB
                   ELSE ColC
               END,
       ColC = CASE WHEN ColA > ColB AND ColA > ColC THEN ColA
                   WHEN ColB > ColA AND ColB > ColC THEN ColB
                   ELSE ColC
               END
  FROM #EverydayImShuffling

SELECT *
  FROM #EverydayImShuffling
```

```
ID  ColA    ColB    ColC
------------------------
96  13      25      84
97  8       78      101
```

Edit:

Needed a little work to get the case exactly right, but this should demo that it's valid (or at least it was for me with a couple of hundred random rows)

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #EverydayImShuffling
CREATE TABLE #EverydayImShuffling (ID INT IDENTITY, ColA INT, ColB INT, ColC INT)
INSERT INTO #EverydayImShuffling (ColA, ColB, ColC) VALUES
(25 ,  13, 84 ),
(101,  78, 8  )

WHILE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #EverydayImShuffling) < 200
BEGIN
 INSERT INTO #EverydayImShuffling (ColA, ColB, Colc) VALUES
 (ROUND(((100 - 1 -1) * RAND() + 1), 0) - 1,
 ROUND(((100 - 1 -1) * RAND() + 1), 0) - 1,
 ROUND(((100 - 1 -1) * RAND() + 1), 0) - 1)
END

SELECT *
  FROM #EverydayImShuffling

UPDATE #EverydayImShuffling
   SET ColA = CASE WHEN ColA <= ColB AND ColA <= ColC THEN ColA
                   WHEN ColB <= ColC AND ColB <= ColA THEN ColB
                   WHEN ColC <= ColB AND ColC <= ColA THEN ColC
               END,                           
       ColB = CASE WHEN ColA >= ColB AND ColA <= ColC THEN ColA
                   WHEN ColB >= ColA AND ColB <= ColC THEN ColB
                   WHEN ColC >= ColA AND ColC <= ColB THEN ColC
                   WHEN ColC >= ColB AND ColC <= ColA THEN ColC
                   WHEN ColB >= ColC AND ColB <= ColA THEN ColB
                   WHEN ColA >= ColC AND ColA <= ColB THEN ColA
               END,                           
       ColC = CASE WHEN ColA >= ColB AND ColA >= ColC THEN ColA
                   WHEN ColB >= ColA AND ColB >= ColC THEN ColB
                   WHEN ColC >= ColA AND ColC >= ColA THEN ColC
               END
  FROM #EverydayImShuffling

SELECT *
  FROM #EverydayImShuffling
```

I validated it in excel, comparing the before and after totals, and then validating the numbers where in the right order for each row.

You'll probably want to validate yourself before you run it against any real data.

Comment: CASE was one of the options I was toying around with but I think I'm just being picky and don't like to hard core that many conditional statements into a procedure if I don't have to

Comment: Does this cover all possible combinations of values? I started on this approach and but it seemed hard to consider all options - but maybe I was overthinking it.

Comment: Yep, that's the down side. If it's more complicated than the declared logic you could well be in for a fun time writing your own sort via a case expression :)

Comment: @DaleK it's gonna need some tweaking, I tested it out with 200 rows of random data and there are some blind spots.

Comment: I thought that might be the case :) thats why I when the unpivot/pivot route.

Comment: It was rather annoying, but I think the edit got it where it needs to be.

Comment: Wow - now its getting complex :) pretty much why I gave up on that approach.